# How to check if physical sd card is removed/mounted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard, mount

How can I check if a physical sd card is mounted or removed?

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Defining a broadcast receiver with this intent filter does not react on anything

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
// External SD card not mounted
}else{
// External SD card mounted
}
```

Comment: But it will only work on internal storage, which is always mounted.There is sdcard0 and extSDCard, I need to check extSDCard.External Storage seems to be internal storage, at least on my devices (Galaxy S2 and Galaxy Tab)

Comment: @Nachbar90, did you find solution for this?